# Getting coordinates of a placemark from kml

Tags: android, kml

I want to do some computations for distance between the user's current location and the placemarks on the map (which is loaded from a kml file) but in order to do that I need to access the markers' locations from the kml file. I tried to do that by:

```
 for (KmlContainer container : layer.getContainers()) {
        if (container.hasProperty("coordinates")) {
            LatLng from = (container.getProperty("coordinates"));
```

But (container.getProperty("coordinates")) actually returns a string apparently. Is there a way I can get the coordinates as a LatLng?

Comment: I'm not familiar with kml specs, but was is the string content? Maybe it's easy to parse it to LatLng. Also, maybe this helps (kml utility library from google) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#features

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you need to get the coordinate as LatLng. The Java code below is for Android.

```
for(KmlPlacemark placemark: kmlLayer.getPlacemarks()) {
    if(placemark.getGeometry().getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
        KmlPoint point = (KmlPoint) placemark.getGeometry();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(point.getGeometryObject().latitude, point.getGeometryObject().longitude);
    }
}
```